# How to arrange two textviews(First textview should be at left side of screen& Second textview should be at center of screen) in android

Tags: android-relativelayout

I want to arrange the text views as per following way:

- First text view should be left side of screen.
- Second text view should be center of screen.

Currently i am using the relative layout and following is the code and sample image screen shot.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:id="@+id/header_layout">

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:id="@+id/back_navigation"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        style="@style/LargeTextSizeStyle.Bold.CeruleanColor"/>

<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="Text2"
        style="@style/LargeTextSizeStyle.Bold.CeruleanColor"/>
```

[Layout sample screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NARfq.png)

The text views are arranged properly if they have small length of texts. **But issue is two text views are overlapping to each other when they have big length of texts.**

Can you please suggest me to solve the issue

Answer (score 0):

You should change `wrap_content` to a fixed number,like :

```
<com.gui.home.ui.customviews.CustomTextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:text="Text1"
        android:id="@+id/back_navigation"
        android:drawablePadding="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        style="@style/LargeTextSizeStyle.Bold.CeruleanColor"/>
```

Comment: I mean you can check the tick at the left of my answer to give me some reputation point xD